Making Android Use Local DNS Server
I have local DNS (bind9) and DHCP (isc-dhcp-server) working to the point where my desktop and servers can see each other using the domain voncorax.internal. However, I also have two Samsung devices running Android 14. I have been able to get proper address resolution by configuring static IP and specifying my DNS server's IP address for both DNS1 and DNS2, but my devices are unable to resolve any names on my LAN when configured via DHCP. (Android appears to be forcing DNS2 to be 8.8.4.4.)
Is there any way to set up my DNS and/or DHCP servers so Android will preferentially use my LAN's DNS server?

Have you disabled Privacy DNS settings in advanced networking Android settings? https://support.google.com/fi/answer/2819583?hl=en#zippy=%2Cprivate-dns

I have, and they're still picking up 8.8.4.4 and refusing to find my server.

How do you test DNS resolution on Android? Have you captured traffic on your DNS server to see if the phone performs some network communication wit the DNS server after e.g. after a reboot?

@Robert I've just been trying to access the server from Firefox. Also, PingTools can ping nodes by IP but gives an Unknown Host error when passed an FQDN, even though the LAN view shows the correct node FQDN.

android phone: 192.168.10.223
local dns: 192.168.10.212
Run the following iptables command on your router
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.10.223 -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.213:53
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.223 -d 192.168.10.213 -p udp --dport 53 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.0.8
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.10.223 -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.4.4 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.213:53
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.223 -d 192.168.10.213 -p udp --dport 53 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.0.4

The reason for modifying the source address is so that the dns response packets will go back to the router for processing instead of being sent directly through the local switch; since nat will have a record of the address translation, there is no need to add an iptables rule for the return direction

The only way I've solved this is by using a VPN app to force my local (internal) nameserver.  Otherwise, I've confirmed by tcpdump that the phone never queries my internal DNS server as advertised by my own DHCP server.  I've tried blocking outgoing DoH etc to see if it would failover to my advertised internal DNS, but not been successful.
